Induction does not preserve ordering between cardinality of sets?
Consider building a binary tree and consider it as a collection of points and edges. Here is one with five levels, numbered level $1$ at the top with $1$ node to level $5$ at the bottom with $16$ nodes.

Imagine building this in stages by level. Level one has $1$ node and $1$ path. Level $2$ adds an additional $2$ nodes for a total of $3$ nodes in the structure, but of course there are only $2$ paths (through the full tree). I will always consider a path as that which traverses level $1$ to level $n$.
So at level $n$ we have a total of $2^n-1$ nodes (in the entire tree), but the number of paths is only $2^{n-1}$. Thus, at each stage of construction, we have strictly fewer paths than the total number of nodes in the tree. Of course, the number of paths at level $n$ is exactly the number of nodes at that particular level.
If we allow ourselves to iterate this as $n$ ranges over all of $\mathbb N$, we end up with an uncountably infinite number of paths.
This feels counterintuitive and paradoxical. I am sure there is a standard explanation for why this iterative process does not respect the ordering between the number of nodes and paths. So my question is: what is the explanation for this phenomenon? More generally, I welcome any insight into how to think about this too and especially pointing out the errors in my thinking.
It seems like the principle is that induction does not preserve order relations between cardinality of sets (or of sequences of sets more precisely). E.g. let $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be sequences of sets such that their cardinalities are always ordered $|A_n|\leq|B_n|$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Assume that "$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=A$" and "$\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n=B$" exist in some appropriate sense. Then we can have $|A|>|B|$. (I'm not sure how to make the idea rigorous in the tree example. I've only really seen such a limit defined for nested sequences of sets.)
One other thought is that I am mixing the concept of natural numbers and cardinal numbers. Thinking about these as sequences of natural numbers, they don't converge as they are just unbounded as the tree grows. But as sequences of cardinal numbers, they do sort of "converge" in some sense, to $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ (assuming these are the appropriate symbols here, correct me if I'm wrong.). But I don't think my standard real analysis-style of thinking applies in this situation. I'm probably just naively thinking about the relevant set-theoretic issues here...

As you iterate through, you only see the finite paths the tree, not the infinite, and indeed $\lim_n 2^{n-1} = \lim_n (2^n-1 )= \aleph_0$ and indeed there are $\aleph_0$ finite paths. The phenomenon that once we complete the infinite tree, the number of paths jumps in value is often referred to as "discontinuity of the continuum function", i.e. $\lim_n 2^n = \aleph_0\ne 2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\lim_n n} .$

@spaceisdarkgreen that's a helpful comment about there being countably many finite paths (even on the entire infinite tree). I think that solves the main problem in my intuition. Then the transfinite inductive jump answers the rest.

Another connection with what's going on here is "inverse vs direct limits". If $X_n$ is the set of paths of length $\le n$, there are natural maps $X_n\to X_{n+1}$, which give rise to the direct limit: the set of all finite paths. There are also natural maps $X_{n+1}\to X_n$, given by truncating the paths of length $n+1$. These give rise to the inverse limit: the set of all finite and infinite paths. If you used the sets of paths of length exactly $n$ instead, you'd get the set of all infinite paths. This is related to $2$-adic integers.. In general, inverse limits can often be big!

The reason the inductive argument fails is that it's a transfinite induction and you can't prove the inductive step for limit ordinals.  In particular, you can't prove the inductive step for the limit ordinal $\omega$.

I think this is the answer. Now I think I can have an introductory understanding for why the concept of limit ordinal is special and important.
